# How deny access to the previous page when a user have logged out in django?

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-views, django-1.8

I'm a newbie in django, im using the 1.8 version in a Ubuntu server, i made the log in and logout process successfully but when my users try to go to the previous page,  they can see it as an anonymous user. How can i deny the access?

I tried to use a if on my views.py but doesn't work:

```
def login(request):
    if not request.user.is_authenticated():
        return render(request,"base.html",{})
    return render(request,"general.html",{})

@login_required 
def general(request):
    return render(request,"general.html")
```

Hope someone can help me.

EDIT:
I'm using the default urls of django to login and log out.

```
url(r'^$','django.contrib.auth.views.login', {'template_name': 'base.html'}, name='login'),
url(r'^logout/$', 'django.contrib.auth.views.logout', {'next_page': 'login'}, name='logout'),
```

Comment: They can see the `general` page when they're logged out? Or only when they hit the back button on their browser? If they can see it when hitting the back button, that may just be their browser caching the page. If they refresh it, will they be able to see the page?

Comment: Only when they hit the back button after been logged out, if i refresh the page instead the `general` page the `login` page is shown

Comment: Along with login_required in your views, made changes in your template. This will prevent them to see even if they hit back button. I have added the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it using a simple script that makes a reload at the moment when the user logs out that "clear" the cache, probably that's not the proper way to do it but works for me, i'll try to keep searching a better way to do it. If anyone knows it, please share.

Answer (score 0):

You can hide the template by using,

```
{% if user.is_authenticated %}
<html></html>
{% else %}
<html> add for logged out user</html>
{% endif %}
```

This will prevent the users to see your page if they hit back button after logged out.

Edit: In your logout function you can use this,

```
from django.views.decorators.cache import cache_control

@cache_control(no_cache=True, must_revalidate=True)
 def your_function()
   #add your code
 return
```

This will clear cache after a user logged out.

Comment: Why will this prevent them from seeing it? If it's cached in the browser then why would template tags ever be called?

Comment: it doesn't work either, so i have to clear the caché in the logout process?

Comment: @ManuelHdezGalván You can check out the answer I have edited. Now change your logout and let me know.

Comment: Hi @BidhanMajhi Hi, sorry for answer till today, i tried but still not working, i'm not using a function to make the logout process, i'm using it in the `urls.py` of django, i edited the question with my urls.